# XSL - Inherit all objects and extend it

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I got a question regarding XSL(T). I want to know is it possible to extend a template without affecting the original template? Let me explain myself by code.

I have the following original template (original-template.xsl):

```
<xsl:template match="dom:Textbox">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@password = 'true'">
          <xsl:attribute name="type">password</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Now I have an extension file (extension.xsl) created to overrule or to in ideal situation extend the original xsl file:

```
 <xsl:template match="dom:Textbox">
      <xsl:if test="@cssClass='placeholder-input'">
        <xsl:attribute name="placeholder">Enter your email</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

Now running this will overrule everything that is stated within my original template. I want to know is there a method where everything of my original template can be inherited and my placeholder code is been added to the original template?

Comment: No, templates cannot be extended. Why do you need to extend the template? How about writing more specific templates, along the lines of `dom:Textbox[@cssClass='placeholder-input']`? If there is a lot of code that is common to several templates, consider writing a _named_ template.

Comment: Are you using `xsl:include` or `xsl:import` here? If you are using `xsl:import` you could probably make use of `xsl:apply-imports` to apply the template in the imported XSLT file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `xsl:import` and `xsl:apply-imports` e.g. assuming your `extension.xsl` use `<xsl:import href="original-template.xsl"/>` it can then use

```
 <xsl:template match="dom:Textbox">
      <xsl:if test="@cssClass='placeholder-input'">
        <xsl:attribute name="placeholder">Enter your email</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-imports/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Additionally XSLT 2.0 has `xsl:next-match`.